# Knights and Knaves Truth Table Logic

Tags: logic

I have a question on a knights and knaves riddle.

> Person $A$ says: "One of us is a knight and one of us is a knave".
> Person $B$ says: "That's correct"

I have deduced through brute force logic that they must both be knaves as the other scenarios are not possible.

However my question is, how would you identify person $A$, and person $B$ as a knight or a knave with a truth table? I understand how truth tables work, I just am confused on how you could represent and confirm this with a truth table. An example of this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a$ be the statement "A is a knight" and let $b$ be the statement "B" is a knight.  Then $a$ is true is and only if the statement $$(\neg a\wedge b)\vee (a \wedge \neg b)\tag1 $$ Since B confirms A, $b$ is also true if and only if $(1)$.  So the statement you want is $$(a\leftrightarrow(\neg a\wedge b)\vee (a \wedge \neg b))\wedge(b\leftrightarrow(\neg a\wedge b)\vee (a \wedge \neg b))$$